# flazx downloads: legal?

Tags: discussion, legal, downloads

I'm trying to decide how heavily to police something...

I've been alerted to a number of flazx links on stackoverflow that link to rapidshare downloads of copyright material (i.e. e-books).

Since the content is copyright, my instinct is that these rapidshare links are simply illegal.

The easy option is to manually replace flazx links with amazon; but: how heavily would *you* enforce this? (I'm trying to think how to respond to such links (especially the direct rapidshare/etc ones)... edit? removal? punitive?)

Comment: did you get the flag I sent you about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391523/what-are-some-good-free-programming-books/392926#392926 Someone did that for another link; I removed the link. I'd say remove the revisions that even links those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the idea of replacing them with Amazon links, personally.

And if it's copyrighted material it is *certainly* illegal and we have historically removed links like that in the past.

Answer (score 1):

I'd certainly wouldn't change it to links to Amazon but just to the name of the material. But yes, I would edit it.

Comment: Perhaps the publishers own page? But everyone understands what Amazon is, at least...

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

I'd go with editing + light reprimand via comment (backed up by some quote from the SO 'rules')

Answer (score 0):

There are countries were downloading copyrighted materials is not illegal, only making it available. Shocking, but true. The reasoning goes: you cannot be expected to know whether a content made available to you is copyrighted. Therefore I would comment on the questions, as I proposed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8492/should-an-answer-that-encourages-illegal-activity-be-marked-as-offensive).